# Pylons routing through folders

Tags: python, api, routes, versioning, pylons

I am kind of new to pylons and I have the task of designing a API versioning system. I want to store the different versions of the APIs in different folders. For example:

```
controllers/APIVersion/v1/clientAPI.py -- Version 1
controllers/APIVersion/v2/clientAPI.py -- Version 2
controllers/APIVersion/v3/clientAPI.py -- Version 3
```

The requests to get to these APIs should look like this:

```
curl 'http://mySite/v1/clientAPI/get/' -- Should bring me to the first version
curl 'http://mySite/v2/clientAPI/get/' -- Should bring me to the second version
```

I know I can do this through routing.py. This was my first idea that didn't seem to work:

```
map.connect('/APIVersion/{version}/{controller}/{action}')
```

Any ideas on how to route to the desired location? Also, feel free to comment on my versioning approach. I welcome the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing Routes sees is the URL (which is also the first argument to `connect`).
You're trying to access the API using URLs like `/v1/clientAPI/get/` but you've configured your routing.py with routes like `/APIVersion/{version}/{controller}/{action}`. So there's no match.
The simplest "fix" would be use URLs like `http://mySite/APIVersion/v1/clientAPI/get/` for v1 or `http://mySite/APIVersion/v2/clientAPI/get/` for v2 and so on (you'll also need to make sure that APIVersion & all v1 to vX are packages + the controller class in each `clientAPI.py` is called `ClientapiController`).
If that's not an option (as in you still want to use URLs like `/v1/clientAPI/get/` but have the controllers directory layout like `/APIVersion/v1/clientAPI/get/`) than you'll need to use a method similar to the one listed [here](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/routes+-+dynamic+controllers).